# Accessing data from PHP array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array as follows

```
$user_followers = [
    [
        'user_id'   => '1',
        'followers' => ['3', '4', '5']
    ],
    [
        'user_id'   => '2',
        'followers' => ['1', '5']
    ],
    [
        'user_id'   => '3',
        'followers' => ['1', '5', '4']
    ],
    [
        'user_id'   => '4',
        'followers' => ['3', '1', '5']
    ],
    [
        'user_id'   => '5',
        'followers' => ['1', '2', '4']
    ],
];
```

What I need to do is obtain the followers data array based on the user_id value therefore if I have a `user_id` of 2 it will return an array containing the `followers` array data. I am not sure whether I need to re organise my array structure to do this.

Comment: Omg aren't they duplicate keys ?

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran yes, he's apparently missing `),array(` a few times.

Comment: @bwoebi, You got some binocular eyes mate :)

Comment: A quick simplification of your data structure would make the task a lot easier - move 'user_id' out of the array and make it the key, like: `$user_followers = [1 => [3,4,5], 2 => [1, 5], 3 => [1,5,4], 4 => [3,1,5], 5 => [1,2,4]];`

Comment: @TML: That's what http://php.net/array_column is for, example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23594245/367456

Comment: Sure, @hakre, you can certainly ask PHP to coerce your data into the desired structure; or you can just give it a bit of thought and give yourself a more useful structure to begin with. :)

Comment: sure you should model the data so that it is beneficial when you operate on it. Mapping some key in PHP arrays can actually mean that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first of all, your array should look like this:

```
$users = array(
        array(
            'user_id'   => '1',
            'followers' => array('3', '4', '5')
        ),
        array (
            'user_id'   => '2',
            'followers' => array('1', '5')
        ),
        array(
            'user_id'   => '3',
            'followers' => array('1', '5', '4')
        ),
        array(
            'user_id'   => '4',
            'followers' => array('3', '1', '5')
        ),
        array(
            'user_id'   => '5',
            'followers' => array('1', '2', '4')
        ),
    );
```

You can create a function like this:

```
// Returns the array of user data
function getUserFollowers($users, $desired_id) {
    foreach($users as $user) {
        if ( $user['user_id'] == $desired_id ) {
            return $user['followers'];
        }
    }
}
```

Where the parameter *$users* is the array of all your users and *$id* is the id of the user you are looking for. The foreach loop iterates through all of your users and checks the id of all the users. If it matches, it returns the array of followers.

Note, this process can use up a lot of memory if the array is huge. Where are you loading this data from?

Comment: The data is currently from a small array as I am creating a student prototype.

Comment: If you are loading the data from a database, I recommend changing the method of data retrieval as this can take longer and use up more memory. Otherwise, use the getUserFollowers() function.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily key the `followers` to all `user_id`s with [`array_column()`](http://php.net/array_column), then you can access the followers by their user id:

```
$followers = array_column($user_followers, 'followers', 'user_id');

print_r($followers[2]);
```

Which gives ([Demo](https://eval.in/149616)):

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 5
)
```

This works as long as the key is unique (which is the third parameter of `array_column` and seems the case here as `user_id` sounds like a unique id).

Answer (score 2):

If you version php < 5.5 you can't use array_column

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function array_column()
```

So you can create your own function:

```
if ( !function_exists('array_column') ) {
  function array_column( $collection, $field, $keyfield = null, $desired_id = null ) {
    $items = array();
    foreach ( $collection as $k => $item ) {
      $key = $keyfield ? $item[$keyfield] : $k;
        if( $desired_id == $key){     
            $items[] = $item[$field];
        }
    }
    return $items;
  }
}

var_dump(array_column($user_followers, 'followers', 'user_id', 2));
```

Result:

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string '1' (length=1)
      1 => string '5' (length=1)
```

Example - [Demo](https://eval.in/149622)